# Function vanishing at a point but not in any neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x\in X$ not isolated. Is there a function $f\in C(X)$ such that $f(x)=0$ but for all open neighborhoods $U\subseteq X$ of $x$ there is a $y\in U$ such that $f(y)\neq 0$? I am particularly interested in the case $X$ is compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: I suppose that the OP would like to know if this holds for any topological space $X$ which is compact and Hausdorff? If you ask $X$ to be a metric space, the answer is yes with $f(y)=d(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There need not be such a function. Let $X=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology; $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, but every continuous real-valued function on $X$ is constant on a nbhd of the point $\omega_1$.

It **is** always possible if $X$ is Tikhonov and first countable, as in that case each singleton is a zero-set.